# What does the completion handler look like in C# when trying to animate?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, uiviewanimation

I want translate this code

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
    animations:^{
        self.datePicker.alpha = 0.0f;
    }
    completion:^(BOOL finished){
        self.datePicker.hidden = YES;
    }
];
```

to Xamarin iOS:

```
UIView.Animate (0.25,
    animation: () => {
        this.datePicker.Alpha = 0.0f;
    },
    completion: (finished){
        this.datePicker.Hidden = true;
    }
);
```

The problem is in the `completion` block. How do I use the bool `finished` here?

I get

> Unexpected Symbol `{`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's basic [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/bb397687.aspx).

```
UIView.Animate (0.25,
    animation: () => {
        this.datePicker.Alpha = 0.0f;
    },
    completion: () => {
        this.datePicker.Hidden = true;
    }
);
```

Or since you have only one statement in your body, you can cut it down even further to

```
UIView.Animate (0.25,
    animation: () => this.datePicker.Alpha = 0.0f,
    completion: () => this.datePicker.Hidden = true
);
```

Comment: Delegate 'Monotouch.Foundation.NSAction' does not take '1' arguments

Comment: See edit. I don't know why the Xamarin.iOS API is different from the Cocoa signatures, I thought they were meant to be exact copies - sort of.

Comment: If I get this right: in the original `Objective C` code there is a bool which is set to true if it is finished. In `Xamarin` I don't need such a variable because it's automatically called?

Comment: It seems to me that the Xamarin people didn't bother with the success parameter of the completion action. I've certainly never had to use it.

Comment: That parameter can be useful.  I requested Xamarin to add it.  See the bug for it here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=27334

Comment: @jgoldberg's answer should be recognised as the correct answer. It was probably a mistake not to include finished in the first place, but then it had to be kept like that for backwards compatibility and UIView.AnimateNotify was added instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use UIView.AnimateNotify() to get the delegate for the completion handler that uses the bool parameter.